# Convert a path (which is an image) to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I provide for the User to upload an image.

But if it is not done, I want to set a default image in an images folder.

How do I set the model property of type 'HttpPostedFileBase' to the image that is located at the path that I set programmatically?

The model property:

```
 public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedImage { get; set; }
```

I have tries these with no success.

This one I get: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'.

```
 if (userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage == null)
 {
   // Set a default.
   userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage = 
   "F:\\GbngWebClient\\GbngWebClient\\Images\\Avatar.png";
 }
```

This one I get: property or indexer 'HttpPostedFileBaseInputStream' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

```
 if (userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage == null)
 {
   // Set a default.
   String pathImage = Server.MapPath("F:\\GbngWebClient\\GbngWebClient\\Images\\Avatar.png");
   userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage.InputStream = new FileStream(pathImage, FileMode.Open);
 }
```

This one I get: Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'.

```
 if (userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage == null)
 {
   // Set a default.
   byte[] imageArray = 
   System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@F:\\GbngWebClient\\GbngWebClient\\Images\\Avatar.png");
   userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage = imageArray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to create a class of this type. The class is for receiving file data from a HTTP Request. Usually you get data *from* this class using its input stream. The msdn docs have an example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpPostedFile_InputStream

What you want to do is get the File Stream from the HttpPostedFileClass, and if there is none, get that file stream from your default location. You can declare an empty memory stream to start with and fill that stream from either the HttpPostedFile or your local resource where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try use check null in View like:

```
if (userProfileForSaveVM.UserProfileSingleVM.UploadedImage != null)
{
   <img src= "@Url.Content("~/uploads/FileUpload12011_03_02_11_49_22.jpg")" alt="IMAGES" />
}
```